SDK location not found in Android Studio
I am facing this problem even i have set the enviroment variable for both JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME still i am not able to ressolve this issue.
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\application\local.properties'.`

I was actually working on windows 11 machine and published the code to gitlab that time it was working fine but then i formatted my system and downgraded my system to windows 10 and cloned the project but it was showing the above issue i have added all the essential things but cant figure out what I am missing.


I added enviroment variable
Tried to add sdk with version 17
Added JavaHOME and AndroidHOME
